# Generate heatmap using Pandas and Weasyprint

Tags: html, pdf, pandas, heatmap, weasyprint

I have a pandas data frame , which I am trying to render as a PDF using Weasyprint. For other formatting changes , I have used 'column formatters' and modified the underlying HTML.

```
int_frmt = lambda x: '<div style="text-align:right">%s</div>' % '{0}'.format(int(round(x))) 
frmt = {col: int_frmt for col in df.columns if df.dtypes[col] in [np.dtype('int64'), np.dtype('float64')]}
```

How can I add a Heatmap to the PDF in the same manner ( by modifying the underlying HTML )?

One way of doing this, which I could think, is to generate a separate pandas dataframe which contains all the color information, and then superimpose the two frames by iterating over all the values and modifying each cell individually.

I am looking for a more direct and comprehensive solution, or an API, of the like we have in Matplotlib, Seaborn ( heatmap() function ).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you trying to create a heatmap or add an existing image (of a heatmap) to HTML code?

Comment: I am trying to create a heatmap, using the values in pandas.

Comment: There are many examples of heat maps using pandas on this website. Which ones did you look at and why did they fall short of solving your problem? Additionally, seaborn is built with pandas in mind, so I'm surprised that its heat map function doesn't suit your needs. Lastly, if the main purpose of this question is to learn how to generate an image of a heat map, I recommend removing the bits about weasyprint since that seems orthogonal to the heat map question.

Comment: @PaulH - My end goal is to render a PDF using pandas and weasyprint. So, to add formatting changes to the final PDF, **I am using Column formatters which modify the underlying HTML **, which is used to generate a PDF. **What Matplatlib and Seaborn will do is they will render an image for me**, which I do not want. I do not want the image, I want the underlying HTML , so that I can use it render a PDF using Weasyprint.

Comment: In that case, I have two recommendations: 1) edit your question to include those clarifications and 2) look into matplotlib's SVG backend. If you can include SVG in weasyprint documents, that seems like the quickest path forward. Also, you might want to look at the `pandas.DataFrame.__repr_html__` method and see if you can build from that to make your own e.g., `DataFrame.__repr_html_heatmap__` method. I'm sure the pandas developers would welcome such a contribution to the library

Comment: @avinavsingla did u figure out the way of including plots in a pdf report using weasy print?